# Unable to install wine on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package, ubuntu-14.04, uninstallation, wine

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. I have done all the updates and upgrades.
When I try to install wine, it wants to uninstall (remove) many other packages. Not just one or two programs, but a big list of other packages.
Any ideas what might cause this problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: So it seems that whenever anybody asks this on askubuntu.com admins unhelpfully mark it as closed and redirect to "OMG how do I use computer". 

Here are some links on this problem:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/581952/unable-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04

http://askubuntu.com/questions/459280/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-14-04

Actually non of the solutions in any of the duplicates worked for me. 

Instead, this worked: 
Goto libcgmanager0 on software center change the version to v0.24(default). Then $: aptitude install libcgmanager0-dev ;  aptitude install wine ;

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

it is okay, the system try to solve the dependence problem with these packages. But I recommend to use windows virtual box rather then wine, and wine is difficult to uninstall to beginner.

Comment: I have tried this option too. No success! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal to learn how to start and use a terminal for the command prompt
2. Once you have a terminal, type these two commands:

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install wine

The first one refreshes the list of packages; the second does the actual installation.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask if aptitude is suggesting 'autoremove' for those packages? If so, these packages has no use nor dependency anymore and is therefore safe to remove from the system, before or after installing wine. Here is a good [further explanation](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=996053).